# Why can't I use git commit and git push?

Tags: git, github, atom-editor, commit

I want to commit to a repository via the Atom code editor. But while doing that, I get strange errors. "Unable to commit - /usr/bin/env: 'bash': No such file or directory" (see screenshot attached). I get the same errors when trying to commit via GitHub Desktop. The strange thing is that it worked before and we didn't change anything concerning the cuntributor structure in the mean time. So that error just came out of nowhere. Even funnier, I can commit via the command line (regular Windows cmd and git bash both work).

Once I've committed, I can't push my commit via Atom or GitHub Desktop (see screenshot), but I can push my commit via both of the command line tools.

Since I am able to commit via the command line it's more of a convenience thing to commit and push via the GUI programs, but I'd still like to have that convenience (and know why it doesn't work). My friend (who is also a contributor in this repo) can easily commit via these GUI programs with no errors. For reference: There are no pre-commit hooks.

EDIT: With another repository committing and pushing work just fine. I tried deleting and recloning the repo and reinstallung node modules and it still fails.

[image]

Comment: By looking at that error message not sure what file it is looking for and can't find.
Make sure you have /usr/bin/env and bash (usually: /bin/bash) and they are sane, means you can execute them.
If they are not okay then install/reinstall them.
If they are okay then try running your git command under strace that will tell which file it is looking for but can't find.

Comment: It is quite clear: you missed `bash` interpreter in the *$PATH* or it's completely absent on the system.

Comment: @Sumit and 0andriy It seems to be a repository issue. I can commit and push to other repos from Atom/Github Desktop.

Comment: Maybe this repository has some custom hooks. Look inside .git/hooks and see if there's any pre-commit or pre-push hooks configured.

Comment: @crea1 there are files called `pre-commit.sample` and `pre-push.sample` but as it seems they shouldn't be called because they have the .sample extension, meaning that I don't have any hooks, right?